# How to Reset In-App Purchase?

Tags: windows-phone-8, marketplace

I am testing my in-app purchases, I uploaded my app to the windows store as beta and made an in-app product.

I tried it out and noticed a bug, I want to reset the in app purchase(it is hide ads) but I am not sure how to do this.

I want it so it is like the user account that bought the in-app never actually bought it.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you are talking about a *durable* in app purchase, since consumable purchases can be bought as many times as one wants.

Once a durable purchase is made, it is [permanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206950%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to the account. A user *could* call customer service to have this reversed, but it is not common (I have done this).

However it is unlikely that a rep would reverse a free in app purchase for a beta app to assist in testing.

If you would like to test your app without having to deal with those issues, [Microsoft has provided guidance in how to test in app purchases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

So far as i know, if someone bought something through store, he cannot actually get the money back. If you're releasing app, you should pre-test it to be 100% sure it's working. If you're not sure how is the in-app purchase working, there is a plenty of forum threads about how to do this efficiently. Long story short, if someone already bought this in-app feature, either you cannot block it to him or refund his money.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend testing In App Purchases through the emulator. Every time you restart the emulator it's like booting up a fresh device, so you'll be able to purchase IAPs again.

Comment: How do you test it, I thought the app had to be in "beta" mode and then that device had to be logged in with a windows account that you have allowed.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special with the live ID of your emulator. It should just work. You do need to change the ProductId of your WMAppManifest.xml to match the ProductId that the store has assigned to your beta app though.

Comment: hmm, because when I launch my application and deploy it on my phone and try to use the in app purchase I get an error, I upload the xap file with no changes to the marketplace in beta mode and it works.